# Importing 3d model with multiple skeletons

Tags: xna-4.0, 3dsmax, xna-content-pipeline

I have created an animated butterfly in 3ds Max and try to export it in ".fbx" format to use in XNA, however as soon as I compile, i get the following Errors:

**Warning   1 Multiple skeletons were found in the file. The first skeleton, named "Left.Wing" has been moved to be a child of the scene root. The other, "Right.Wing", will be ignored. Fragment identifier "Right.Wing".**

**Error 2  Vertex is bound to bone "Right.Wing", but this bone is not present in the skeleton.**

Which is confusing since I have the bone Right.Wing . . and I use it to animate the butterfly

I have seen a few possible solution for Blender but none for 3Ds max it would be really helpful if someone could help me out with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I don't use 3DSMax or XNA, I would assume this issue is caused by the left and right wing not sharing a common parent. All the bones should be connected to a common root bone, since most applications (it seems XNA is included) don't support multiple skeletons per model.

Place a bone down the center of your butterfly and make the left and right wing children of that bone.

```
  left       right
    -----|-----
         |
         |
         | root
```

It doesn't need to have any function, but it would make sense to bind the body vertices to it and use it to move the body as part of your flapping motion.

Comment: I guess you are right.. There are only 2 bones **Left.Wing** & **Right.Wing** and they are linked together and also to a dummy node **Butterfly.Root** but not to a single parent root bone as you said

I'm a beginner in 3ds max as well and i followed a youtube tutorial .. is there any work around this? Anyway I can add a parent bone?

[link]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SU2XxjNk7HI [link]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to use 3DSMax. What's the difference between a node (Butterfly.Root) and a bone? Using Blender, I would create the root bone, then extend the wing bones off of that bone. I'm not sure of a way to add one after the fact.

Comment: In my model the node controls the whole butterfly object but the individual bones just control the wings

Comment: Adding the a Root bone does solve the problem, XNA does not give the same Error anymore . . However the Rendering is not happening properly . . it renders the object very small but this seems to solve atleast the multiple skeleton problem for now!

Comment: @SwetaDwivedi Great! I would assume the scaling is something to do with the matrix multiplication introduced by the root bone. If the root bone were scaled smaller, it affects every child bone.